# WordPress/WooCommerce Coupon Code - Change Checkout Gateway

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to use a coupon code that when entered only shows Cash on Delivery as a payment type, rather than using the default Paypal option.

At the moment, the only option for people to pay is via PayPal but when this particular coupon code is entered (20% off) I only want to show Cash on Delivery option - is this possible?

Comment: You can bind js code on coupon field update and send ajax request that update payment option via hook

Comment: Would you have an example of this?

Comment: it would be a long code and I don't have woocommerce development environtment to code and test it myself, search for woocommerce ajax, search on how to update payment option via functions, then combine the two, its really hard to help you with just your idea of what you want, you need to at least try something. try reading woocommerce docs for hooks and filter, you probably need a filter like ```woocommerce_available_payment_gateway```